# Default from address is not picking for Salesforce email from Case details Page

Tags: javascript, email, custom-button, notification, send-email

In our system, there were multiple Organization-Wide Email Addresses configured and verified. In that I need to make one default address as "From Address" to everyone. Eg: support@xxx.com.

I am trying to execute the following Javascript code in custom button

```
location.replace('/email/author/emailauthor.jsp?retURL=/{!Case.Id}&p3_lkid={!Case.Id}&rtype=003&p2_lkid={!Case.ContactId}&template_id=00XCXXXXXXXXXXX&p26=support@xxx.com');
```

It is working fine for almost everyone. But for only one user from address is not picking the correct address. What might be the issue with that user? Where I need to set this Default from address? Whether the effected user might have changed his email settings? Debugged in the possible ways, but couldn't able to figure out the issue.

Comment: Have you checked the console for errors?

Comment: Yes. That is what happening now @Seesh

Comment: @SalesforceDeveloper Deleted comment because I thought of rephrasing the question. So the email is sent. The affected user is in a different profile or is it working for other users in that profile?

Comment: @Seesh It is working for other users in the same Profile. I have seen only one user who is getting other different  address.

Comment: @SalesforceDeveloper Because when you set the OWD email address, you have an option for selecting all or particular profiles to use that FROM address.

Comment: Yes! That I am aware of..

Comment: @SalesforceDeveloper Interesting. Up-voted. As your org has multiple OWD email addresses, the wrong FROM address of the affected user vary each and every time or just picks one?

Comment: @Seesh It is picking constantly only one address. I am figuring out whether the user might changed some email settings at his end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Raised this concern with Salesforce Support. Here is their reply.

Email address passing in the URL using p26 parameter (From address) is considered as URL hacking which is not supported. However if you can use the below format of passing from address in the button click javascript code, which seems will resolve the issue.

```
&p26=ORG_WIDE_EMAIL_ADDRESS_RECORD_ID:Email Address:Display Name
```

Example:

```
&p26=0D2XXXXXXXXXXXX:care@xyz.com:XYZ Support
```

Absolutely it's working fine without any issues.